# Как закрыть форму через страницу, которая находится в форме?

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая вот проблема: Мне надо, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку на странице (frame), у меня закрылась форма, на которой находится данная страница. Я пробовал метод Close(), но он не закрывает форму.

```
Admin admin = new Admin();
            admin.Close();
```

Может есть какой-то другой способ? Форма в данном случае не MainWindow и не начальная.

Comment: В WPF нет форм, есть окна, у вас даже в названии это показывается (Main**Window**). Касательно вопроса - задайте себе вопрос, что такое `= new ... ();`? Это создание нового объекта, или получение старого? Думаю, ответ очевиден. Так может вам надо получить уже открытое окно, которое и надо закрывать? Как получить - зависит от конструкции вашего приложения, это можно сделать кучей способов, от передачи через констуктор и свойства, до внедрения зависимостей и контейнеров.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я понимаю что я создаю новый объект. Просто я не знаю как обратится к уже существующему. А скок искал находил, где создают новый объект.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете посоветовать простой способ, который мог бы закрыть старое окно?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел способ работы с активным окном. Код ниже:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is Admin)
    {
        window.Close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Может кому-то тоже поможет.

Comment: Костыль конечно, но если уж на то пошло, то `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Admin>().First().Close();`.

Comment: Или так, чтоб не падало, если окна нет `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Admin>().FirstOrDefault()?.Close();`